# A-Frame Jittering Of 3D Model

Tags: javascript, web, augmented-reality, aframe, ar.js

I am trying to augment a car model using the hiro pattern, but there is jittering.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>augmented reality</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <!-- A FRAME -->
  <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.8.2/aframe.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/jeromeetienne/AR.js/1.6.0/aframe/build/aframe-ar.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/donmccurdy/aframe-extras/v3.8.4/dist/aframe-extras.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://rawgit.com/mayognaise/aframe-gif-shader/master/dist/aframe-gif-shader.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/aframe-event-set-component@^4.0.0/dist/aframe-event-set-component.min.js"></script>
  <!-- import events.js script -->
  <script src="https://rawgit.com/nicolocarpignoli/nicolocarpignoli.github.io/master/ar-playground/events.js"></script>
  <!-- import the webpage's stylesheet -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css">

  <!-- import the webpage's javascript file -->
  <script src="/script.js" defer></script>
</head>

<body>


  <a-scene shadow="type: pcfsoft" embedded arjs='sourceType: webcam; debugUIEnabled: false;' debug>

    <a-marker preset="hiro">
      <a-entity shadow="cast: true" gltf-model="https://cdn.glitch.com/0d1945ac-ed6f-44be-9903-e1c1626575a4%2Fcar.glb?1548349423434" position="0 0 0" crossOrigin="anonymous" response-type="arraybuffer" rotation="0 0 0" scale="0.05 0.05 0.05">
      </a-entity>
    </a-marker>
    <a-entity light="type: ambient; color: #CCC"></a-entity>
    <a-entity camera></a-entity>

  </a-scene>

  <!-- include the Glitch button to show what the webpage is about and
          to make it easier for folks to view source and remix -->
  <div class="glitchButton" style="position:fixed;top:20px;right:20px;"></div>
  <script src="https://button.glitch.me/button.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

When the camera is closer to the marker than the object is jittering (broken textures) is a bit less, but when the camera is far (increase the distance between the marker and camera then the jittering increases as in the attached images.

When Far
[image: When Far]

Closer
[image: Closer]

Far
[image: far roung 2 feet]

Comment: Please Edit the my code in glitch and fix the issue

Comment: These seem the limitations of marker based tracking. I don’t think it’s an implementation issue.

Comment: The [ar] tag refers to the Unix archive utility, not augmented reality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a AR.js bug that could be behind this: https://github.com/jeromeetienne/AR.js/issues/410

One workaround is to add this code before `</body>`:

```
<script>
// Workaround for an AR.js bug (https://github.com/jeromeetienne/AR.js/issues/410)
const sceneEl = document.querySelector('a-scene');
sceneEl.addEventListener('loaded', () => {
    sceneEl.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera();
});
</script>
```

Comment: It Worked But Is There Any Standard Way To Implement ....... And In  A-Frame 0.9.2 
Its not Supportable and Aframe Inspect (Alt+Alt+I) Is Also Blocked After Using This